# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (GT - P5100), shortcut button to close/exit from any app/game

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I am a new user of Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (GT - P5100).

- Is there any shortcut button to close/exit from any app/game?
- Or, any other mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no common shortcut to close/exit any program.  The "android way" is to let the OS decide when to actually close/exit an application.  Just hit the "Home" button or the "Recent apps" buttons to switch to another application when you're done with the current application, or tap the physical power button to turn off the screen.

The OS will take responsibility for deciding when to suspend and when to terminate a background application.  It generally does a good job of this, but some people cannot stand this behavior and so install task manager applications to explicitly terminate background applications.